# Codeigniter JQuery datepicker issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

Hi i am studying web development and am new to this site, im having a problem showing the datepicker with JQuery and CodeIgniter.

Here is my code

VIEW

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to Kinsale property</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.css'); ?>" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Kinsale Property!</h1>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    minDate : 0,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });

            });
    </script>


    <!--load jquery-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-1.10.2.js'); ?>"></script>
    <!--load jquery ui js file-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>
</body>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
</div>

</html>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: and where is your input?

Answer (score 2):

you are skip the tag where your jquery code are targeting i.e.

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

now html5 also provide datepicker just write this line

```
<input type="date" name="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 1):

put input field on you code you miss input type

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```